# Fibers of Rees ring of a filterd $k$-algebra over affine line.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Given a $k$-algebra $U$ with an increasing filtration $U_0\subset U_1\subset\cdots$ such that $U=\bigcup U_i$, set $t$ an indeterminate, define the Rees ring for $U$ as

$$\mathcal{U}=\left\{\sum u_it^i \mid u_i\in U_i\right\}\subset U\otimes k[t].$$

Then $\mathcal{U}$ becomes an graded $k[t]$-algebra by setting $\deg t=1$. The question is about understanding its fibers over $\operatorname{Spec} k[t]$:

> i) The fiber over $t=\lambda\ne0$ is isomorphic to $U$.
>
> ii) The fiber over $t=0$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{gr} U=\bigoplus U_i/U_{i-1}$.

In my immature view, the fiber of $\mathcal{U}$ over $t=\lambda$ is simply $\mathcal{U}\otimes_{k[t]}k[t]/(t-\lambda)$, which is to specialize $\mathcal{U}$ at $t=\lambda$. In this way I can explain i) but still leave ii) unsolved. How does the asscociated graded ring $\operatorname{gr} U$ arise when $t=0$?

Comment: I've made some formatting upgrades to your post - notably, \operatorname{Spec} produces better formatting for $\operatorname{Spec}$ which lets you skip the awkward spacing workaround you had in there before (similarly for \operatorname{gr}) and \mid for the center bar in the set-builder definition of $\mathcal{U}$. As for a non-formatting comment, this is nitpicky (sorry): you talk about the fibers over $\Bbb A^1_k$, but then give algebras instead of schemes - I didn't want to just fix this myself, but adding a couple words about the fiber being Spec of the algebra you mention could be good.

Comment: @KReiser thanks for your correction, and yes, by fiber I mean the the spec of  algebra.  But it seems quite common to mix up fiber and its algebra.

Comment: You're welcome. You're right that it's not so bad (I even said it was nitpicky!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue when I first learned about the Rees algebra. First, the fiber over $t=0$ is the spectrum of $\mathcal{U}/t\mathcal{U}$. It's tempting to simplify this algebra incorrectly: we all know what to do when we see the quotient by the ideal $tR$, which is to set $t=0$ everywhere! Unfortunately this is not correct. Instead, what we need to do is to to look at what $t\mathcal{U}$ is. This is the submodule generated by all terms of the form $tu_n \in U_{n+1}$ where $u_n\in U_n$. This means that any two elements of $U_i$ which differ by an element in $U_{i-1}$ but not in $U_i$ are equal in this quotient. But this is exactly the definition of the associated graded ring.

Comment: What about the question i)?

Comment: @user26857 my reading of the question was that the OP understood how to solve i) and needed help with ii) - that's why I didn't include that. Are you interested in the details of i)? If so, I can add them to the post.